# What is the benefit of declaring custom view attributes in attrs.xml?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I am currently trying to understand why I would need to define the custom attributes of my View in the attrs.xml file. When I create a property with a getter and a setter in my custom view class, I can already use that attribute in XML Layouts. Also I then don't need to retrieve the values in the constructor from the TypedArray.

Comment: You might be able to do that with data binding, but data binding didn't always exist. That's why custom attributes are available, but I wouldn't say that there's necessarily any benefit to them over data binding.

Comment: I don't know how you think you're magically getting that functionality, but writing a getFoo() and a setFoo() does not make Foo an attribute in xml.

Comment: Ah ok, I am fairly new to the concept of Data Binding with Android. So the getter/setter properties can only be used with @{..} if not defined in the attrs.xml ?

Comment: Right. Those annotations will cause the attributes to be generated for you automagically. (That's AFAIK, anyway. I'm not too familiar with the data binding library yet.)